# Are the subsets of homeomorphic spaces also homeomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $W$ be a subset of an $n$-dimensional complex topology vector space $Y$   such that $0\notin W$.We have known that $Y$ is homeomorphic to $C^n$ and let $S$ be the unit sphere of $C^n$.Can anyone show me that $W$ is homeomorphic to $S$?

Comment: What about $W = \varnothing$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly not true. For a counterexample, let $W$ be the set $\{|z|=1\}\cup\{|z|=2\}$, where $Y=\mathbb C$. The unit sphere $S$ is connected, but $W$ is not, so they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: Let me repeat your statement,there are two connect components of $W$ in your counterexample,but $S$ is connected,so they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: @mathon Precisely. Yes.

Comment: @Potato.If I replace $W$ by $Y-V$ where $V$ is a balanced neighborhood of $0$ in $Y$,how about the conclusion?

Comment: @mathon What is a balanced neighborhood?

Comment: For simplicity,consider neighborhood.In fact,every neighborhood of $0$ contains a balanced neighborhood of $0$ in a topological vector space.And a set $B$ in a topological vector space is said to be balanced if $tB\subset B$ for every $t\in C$ with $|t|\leq 1$.

Comment: @mathon Will $W=\{.9\le |z| \le 1\}\cup \{1.9\le|z|\le 2\}$ work, using the same setup as above? From your definition, it seems that $Y-W=V$ is a balanced neighborhood.